# How to add a pod into my flutter / iOS project?

Tags: flutter

This should be very simple, one of the firsts things one do when starts a new project, but when I add the podfile and using usual pod install, it do not work. An error about not finding podfile.lock and manifest.lock shows up.

[image]

Any clue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gotcha. I will answer myself this question in case anybody has the same problem:

open `Flutter/Release.xcconfig` and `Flutter/Debug.xcconfig` and add this line:

- **For `Flutter/Debug.xcconfig`:**

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
```

- **For `Flutter/Release.xcconfig`:**

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
```